# Yield from superclass bypasses subclass block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have two classes:

- Superclass `Inner` has a method `func` which yields values to the caller.
- Subclass `Outer` has an overridden method `func` which calls `Inner.func`, does something with the yielded values, and yields them in turn to its own caller.

When I run this sample code, the block in `Outer` is skipped, and I get this weird `undefined method` error:

```
# subclassed.rb

class Inner
  def func
    puts '  Inner entered func'
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    puts '  Inner leaving func'
  end
end

class Outer < Inner
  def func
    puts 'Outer entered func'
    super.func do |value|
      puts "    Outer received #{value} !!! this never happens !!!"
      yield value
    end
    puts 'Outer leaving func'
  end
end

outer = Outer.new
outer.func do |value|
  puts "      Script received #{value}"
end

$ ruby subclassed.rb
Outer entered func
  Inner entered func
      Script received 1
      Script received 2
      Script received 3
  Inner leaving func
C:/Source/temp/rubytest/subclassed.rb:14:in `func': undefined method `func' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Source/temp/rubytest/subclassed.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

However, if I use encapsulation, everything works as expected:

```
# encapsulated.rb

class Inner
  def func
    puts '  Inner entered func'
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    puts '  Inner leaving func'
  end
end

class Outer
  def initialize
    @inner = Inner.new # (use encapsulation)
  end
  def func
    puts 'Outer entered func'
    @inner.func do |value| # (use encapsulation)
      puts "    Outer received #{value}"
      yield value
    end
    puts 'Outer leaving func'
  end
end

outer = Outer.new
outer.func do |value|
  puts "      Script received #{value}"
end

$ ruby encapsulated.rb
Outer entered func
  Inner entered func
    Outer received 1
      Script received 1
    Outer received 2
      Script received 2
    Outer received 3
      Script received 3
  Inner leaving func
Outer leaving func
```

As an experiment, I changed `def func` to `def func(&callback)`, and `yield 1` to `callback.call(1)`, but I got identical behaviour.

There are some existing posts dealing with subclasses and superclasses, and some others dealing with yields.  However, I can't find anything on this particular problem.  This is the first time I've actually been surprised by something Ruby did in a long time!  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Outer < Inner
  def func(&block)
    puts "outer entered func"
    super do |value|
      puts "   Outer received #{value}"
      block.call(value)
    end
    puts "Outer leaving func"
  end
end
```

I am passing the block with `&block` and then calling block in context of parent's method. Also, just use `super` instead of `super.func` to call parent's method.

**Output:**

```
o = Outer.new
o.func do |val|
  puts "   Script received #{val}"
end
outer entered func
  Inner entered func
   Outer received 1
   Script received 1
   Outer received 2
   Script received 2
   Outer received 3
   Script received 3
  Inner leaving func
Outer leaving func
```

Comment: Just removing the `.func` from `super` works for the first case. On a side note, any idea what `super` returns, if it returns a value as per typical Ruby method?

Comment: @fyooi: I re-read the example snippet you posted and reframed the answer in way I would have written the code. Please check again. `super` just invokes the parent method and returns whatever that parent method is returning.

Comment: Damn cross-language assumptions.  Was clearly thinking of Java's super, not Ruby's.  Thanks!